# Adding a SharePoint Group to a Document Library

Tags: document-library, permissions, groups

I've been asked to create a document library and restrict it's use to a team of people.  I've created the document library and also a SharePoint group with the team members.  I'm able to add the group to the library, but the library is still visible for other users outside of the team/permissions group.

What step am I missing or doing wrong?  I have gone through the process of "Stop Inheriting Permissions" and then "Granting Permissions" and selecting the group name, but it just isn't working :(

Comment: Try checking the effective permissions for one of the users who is not supposed to have access. It will tell you why they have rights.

Comment: Have you removed existing permission after "Stop Inheriting Permissions" and then added permission to your group?

Comment: Also keep in mind that site collection administrators will be able to see all libraries as well.